# What does the save() method save in Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

The question is that what does it save?

- Only the entity?
- The entity and it's relationships?
- Does it saves the relationships and the other end of those relationships?
- Or does it save everything that the entity contains recursively and it acts as an anchor node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It saves the entire subgraph that you have, the entity you're calling the `save()` on acts as an anchor node. In other words, the `save()` function operates recursively, so changes made to any connected nodes or relationships will be saved as well.

The relationships and nodes that are not in the subgraph won't be affected.